# How to set the width of an infowindow for a kml file called via google maps api kmllayer?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to set the width of an infowindow for a kml file called via google maps api kmllayer function?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
 <div id="mapindex"></div>
  <script>
     var map;

     function initMap() {

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapindex'), {
      center: {
        lat: 54.5559,
        lng: 16.5984
      },
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
     });

     var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://www.instead.com.pl/test.kml?time=' + new Date().getTime(),
      map: map,
      preserveViewport: true,
      });
      }
    </script>

     <script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>

 </html>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/innowaktor/onLwxefr/)

But I would like to set the width or max width of the infowindow or just for the name tag.

I have really read all I could find on the internet but cannot find a solution.
Is it even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suppress the standard InfoWindow that is created when you click on the KmlLayer and instead create another InfoWindow that has a maxWidth. Here is a modification to your code:

[Proof of concept JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dacorawutu/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
   html,
  body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#mapindex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="mapindex"></div>
  <script>
     var map;

     function initMap() {

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapindex'), {
        center: {
          lat: 54.5559,
          lng: 16.5984
        },
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
       });

     var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://www.instead.com.pl/test.kml?time=' + new Date().getTime(),
      map: map,
      preserveViewport: true,
      suppressInfoWindows: true
      });

     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

     kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
         var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
         infoWindow.setOptions({
             content: content,
             position: event.latLng,
             maxWidth: 200
         });

         infoWindow.open(map);
     });

    }
    </script>

     <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Preston. The solution works just fine. Have you found any drawbacks to using this solution of displaying an infowindow to the "built in" solution without suppressing? Please give me +1 for the question as I get monits from stackoverflow :)

Comment: I actually prefer the "suppressInfoWindows" options when using KML, as it gives you more options how to display the content for KML features, such as loading information in separate divs or more dynamic styling options

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is (another) bug in the [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)

[proof of concept fiddle (using v=3)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d24gdp1w/29/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#mapindex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapindex"></div>
  <script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapindex'), {
        center: {
          lat: 54.5559,
          lng: 16.5984
        },
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.instead.com.pl/test.kml?time=' + new Date().getTime(),
        map: map,
        preserveViewport: true,
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&v=3">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you @geocodezip for your answer. At first I thought your solution doesn't work but then I realized that the infowindow adjusts to the size of the screen (but not responsively) :). Would you happen to know how to set a fixed/max width? Adding maxWidth to the infowindow code doesn't work. Thanks again for your time.